# Mongo adding a field to a specific object in an array of objects using updateOne during a bulkUpdateOps

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass, subdocument

**Use case**

Adding a field to a specific object in an array of objects using updateOne during a bulkUpdateOps

**Blockers**

1. I have been unable to find a way to identify and update a specific object in the subdocument array of a specific record.
2. I only have access to this DB through MongoDB Compass, and I plan to use the provided mongosh tool.

**Data example**

Our purchaseorders model looks like this:

```
{
   _id: uuid,
   ...rest,
   documents:[
      {
         _id:uuid,
         forignKey2:string (optional),
         keyIWantToAdd:string (optional),
         ...rest
      }
   ]
}
```

So if I have

```
{
   _id:*1,
   documents:[
      {
         _id:*2,
         forignKey2:'no-test',
         ...rest
      },
      {
         _id:*3,
         forignKey2:'test',
         ...rest
      },
   ]
}
```

I want to add a key and value like this (really I'm willing to do anything to set these values, this is just the closest I have been able to get):

```
var bulkUpdateOps = db.purchaseorders.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
bulkUpdateOps.find('*1').updateOne({
   $set:{
      documents.[index of document object with forignKey2:'test' or _id:*3 whichever is easier].keyIWantToAdd:'valueIWantToAdd'
   }
})
bulkUpdateOps.execute();
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might consider using [`Bulk.find.arrayFilters()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.arrayFilters/) to specify the array element you want to update.

Comment: If you know the / one specific sub-document you want to update in the array, then you can use the `$` update operator. It will update the first matching sub-document in the array. Refer array update operators: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/update/#array

Comment: @rickhg12hs That was exactly what I was looking for.
For anyone else using https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.arrayFilters/
the bulk find is being ran on an array of objects like this:
{
   grades:[
      {
         grade: 85,
         mean:  number
      }
   ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rickhg12hs posted exactly what I was looking for. For anyone else using mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.arrayFilters the bulk find is being ran on an array of objects like this: `{ grades:[ { grade: 85, mean: number } ] }`